# Adding Database Using EditText

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i'm new in android programming,i need your help, i want to create an android database using an EditText and Button the button is to submit the data inserted into EditText, i have two Activity the first is the Adding the database and second is viewing the list of database saved. I'm creating a simple "Adding Employee and save it into database"

here's my code on creating a database;

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXITS employee (name VARCHAR, positon VARCHAR);");
```

Now i dont have idea how can i insert the data in ediTtext into Viewing Database any answer is appreciated.Thanks
regards
xyvyre

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How to insert something into the database? How to display the new data in the second activity? How to organize the activities?

Comment: yes sir as a list view i dont have idea how i do it

Answer (score 0):

For some tutorials on how to display data in list view, see the [official Notepad sample](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) (especially the `fillData()` method), or the [Android SQLite Database and ContentProvider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) .